# Data gets mixed up while trying to transfer it to arangodb

Tags: python, multithreading, arangodb, joblib, pyarango

I'm trying to transfer ca. 10GB of json data (tweets in my case) to a collection in arangodb. I'm also trying to use joblib for it:

```
from ArangoConn import ArangoConn
import Userdata as U

import encodings
from joblib import Parallel,delayed
import json
from glob import glob
import time


def progress(total, prog, start, stri = ""):
    if(prog == 0):
        print("")
        prog = 1;
    perc = prog / total
    diff = time.time() - start
    rem = (diff / prog) * (total - prog)
    bar = ""
    for i in range(0,int(perc*20)):
        bar = bar + "|"
    for i in range(int(perc*20),20):
        bar = bar + " "
    print("\r"+"progress: " + "[" + bar + "] " + str(prog) + " of " + 
    str(total) + ": {0:.1f}% ".format(perc * 100) + "- " + 
    time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(rem)) + " " + stri, end="")

def processfile(filepath):
    file = open(filepath,encoding='utf-8')
    s = file.read()
    file.close()
    data = json.loads(s)
    Parallel(n_jobs=12, verbose=0, backend="threading"
    (map(delayed(ArangoConn.createDocFromObject), data))

files = glob(U.path+'/*.json')
i = 1
j = len(files)
starttime = time.time()
for f in files:
    progress(j,i,starttime,f)
    i = i+1
    processfile(f)
```

and

```
from pyArango.connection import Connection
import Userdata as U
import time


class ArangoConn:
    def __init__(self,server,user,pw,db,collectionname):
        self.server = server
        self.user = user
        self.pw = pw
        self.db = db
        self.collectionname = collectionname
        self.connection = None
        self.dbHandle = self.connect()
        if not self.dbHandle.hasCollection(name=self.collectionname):
            coll = self.dbHandle.createCollection(name=collectionname)
        else:
            coll = self.dbHandle.collections[collectionname]
        self.collection = coll

    def db_createDocFromObject(self, obj):
        data = obj.__dict__()
        doc = self.collection.createDocument()
        for key,value in data.items():
            doc[key] = value

        doc._key= str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
        doc.save()

    def connect(self):
        self.connection = Connection(arangoURL=self.server + ":8529",         
        username=self.user, password=self.pw)

        if not self.connection.hasDatabase(self.db):
            db = self.connection.createDatabase(name=self.db)
        else:
            db = self.connection.databases.get(self.db)
        return db

    def disconnect(self):
        self.connection.disconnectSession()


    def getAllData(self):

        docs = []
        for doc in self.collection.fetchAll():
            docs.append(self.doc_to_result(doc))
        return docs


    def addData(self,obj):
            self.db_createDocFromObject(obj)

    def search(self,collection,search,prop):
        docs = []
        aql = """FOR q IN """+collection+""" FILTER q."""+prop+""" LIKE 
            "%"""+search+"""%" RETURN q"""
        results = self.dbHandle.AQLQuery(aql, rawResults=False, batchSize=1)
        for doc in results:
            docs.append(self.doc_to_result(doc))
        return docs


    def doc_to_result(self,arangodoc):
        modstore = arangodoc.getStore()
        modstore["_key"] = arangodoc._key
        return modstore

    def db_createDocFromJson(self,json):

        for d in json:
            doc = self.collection.createDocument()
            for key,value in d.items():
                doc[key] = value
            doc._key = str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
            doc.save()



    @staticmethod
    def createDocFromObject(obj):
        c = ArangoConn(U.url, U.user, U.pw, U.db, U.collection)
        data = obj
        doc = c.collection.createDocument()
        for key, value in data.items():
            doc[key] = value
        doc._key = doc["id"]
        doc.save()
        c.connection.disconnectSession()
```

It kinda works like that. My problem is that the data that lands in the database is somehow mixed up.

[image: Screenshot]

as you can see in the screenshot "id" and "id_str" are not the same - as they should be.

what i investigated so far:

- I thought that at some points the default keys in the databese may "collide" 
  because of the threading so I set the key to the tweet id.
- I tried to do it without multiple threads. the threading doesn't seem to be 
  the problem
- I looked at the data I send to the database... everything seems to be fine

But as soon as I communicate with the db the data mixes up.

My professor thought that maybe something in pyarango isn't threadsafe and it messes up the data but I don't think so as threading doesn't seem to be the problem.

I have no ideas left where this behavior could come from...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot shows the following values:

```
id     : 892886691937214500
id_str : 892886691937214465
```

It looks like somewhere along the way the value is converted to an IEEE754 double, which cannot safely represent the latter value. So there is potentially some precision loss due to conversion.

A quick example in node.js (JavaScript is using IEEE754 doubles for any number values greater than 0xffffffff) shows that this is likely the problem cause:

```
$ node
> 892886691937214500
892886691937214500
> 892886691937214465
892886691937214500
```

So the question is where the conversion does happen. Can you check whether the python client program is correctly sending the expected values to ArangoDB, or does it already send the converted/truncated values?

In general, any integer number that exceeds 0x7fffffffffffffff will be truncated when stored in ArangoDB, or converted to an IEEE754 double. This can be avoided by storing the number values inside a string, but of course comparing two number strings will produce different results than comparing two numbers (e.g. `"10" < "9"` vs. `10 > 9`).

Comment: The conversion happens in arangodb. I'm pretty sure there because I checked the data right before I sent it. So the only thing I can do is to save it as a string?

Comment: Ok, do you happen to know which ArangoDB APIs you are using to store the data and retrieve them back from ArangoDB?
That would help us find out if there is any conversion/truncation, and where. Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently using Arangodb 3.1.28 but an upgrade would be no problem if that would help. on the python side i'm using [pyarango](http://bioinfo.iric.ca/~daoudat/pyArango/) . I don't know which version of magic this does :D

Comment: I'll check if there is anything obvious that leads to truncation in the REST interfaces of ArangoDB.

Comment: Just check with some API calls that integer values up to 0x7fffffffffffffff are received and stored correctly by arangod and also again returned correctly when using the REST interface together with curl. However, when the arangosh is used, it will truncate any bigger integer values by converting them into IEEE754 doubles. This is because JavaScript does not have a built-in number type with enough precision to handle these values. There will also be truncation when the documents are displayed in the web interface. Same reason here: no appropriate number type available in JavaScript.